# ProtectKeysWithCertificate Method not found in asp.net core DataProtection api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, openiddict

I got compile time error on  add of ProtectKeysWithCertificate this line

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDataProtection()
        .SetApplicationName("Testervice")
        .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(newCert);
        //compile time error on ProtectKeysWithCertificate line
       //method not found
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-encryption-at-rest#x509-certificate), `ProtectKeysWithCertificate()` is not available on .NET Core 1.0/1.1 (`netcoreapp1.x`).

If you want to use it, you can target the full .NET Framework (e.g `net461`).

Comment: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: was not found in the key ring got error